# Using the Reduce Function to calculate the Values of more than two integers in a TUPLE

Tags: python-3.x, function, lambda

#I am having trouble calling the third, fourth, and fifth integers from my tuple in the reduce function.
#The program runs when I omit the 'Jeans', 'Ointment', 'and Trees' pairs from the tuple

#The error that I receive is 'NameError: name 'e' is not defined'

#In addition to this would there be a way to prevent a "," from being shown before and after the fifth element in the tuple?

```py
from functools import reduce 

print("Your luxury pack of:", end = " ")

luxuryPack = [
    ('Candy', 5),
    ('Video Games', 64),
    ('Jeans', 69)
    ('Ointment', 7),
    ('and Trees', 420)
]

total = reduce(lambda a,b,c,d,e: a[1] + b[1] +c[1] + d[1], e[1], luxuryPack)

for x in luxuryPack:
      print(x[0], end = ", ") 
                            
print("costs", total)
```

I tried deleting the last three items of the tuple and it worked, however, I can't get the lambda function to work with more than two variables.

Comment: I believe you meant `lambda a,b,c,d,e: a[1] + b[1] +c[1] + d[1] + e[1]`, not `lambda a,b,c,d,e: a[1] + b[1] +c[1] + d[1], e[1])`

Comment: You just want `total = sum(t[1] for t in luxuryPack)`

Comment: Note, if you *did* want to do this with reduce, you would just do `reduce(lambda acc, x: x[1] + acc, luxuryPack, 0)`,In your own attempt, `lambda a,b,c,d,e:` is not really the correct signature for a reducer function, which should simply be `lambda acc, val` where `val` is the current value and `acc` is the accumulator...